# Modifying MCP-counter package

Tags: r, package, mcps

I want to use MCP-counter package to assess TME composition in glioblastoma. But, if want to do this, I should modify this package by including microglial signature and removing fibroblast MCP-scores. I would be grateful if any one show  me how to modify this package according to this explanation.

I tried to find this r package and open the signatures file in it( https://github.com/ebecht/MCPcounter). However, I do not know how to remove this fibroblast score and how to replace it with microglia score in this section.